# pip3 install django on ubuntu

Tags: python, django, pip

Trying to install djnago on my Ubuntu but I fail to do that. I guess this is due to the fact I have python 2/7 and python 3 on my Ubunutu:

```
pip3 install django
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/itaybz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3126, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/home/itaybz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3110, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/itaybz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3139, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/home/itaybz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 583, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/home/itaybz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 596, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/home/itaybz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 784, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==9.0.1' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

The following is installed on the ubunuto:

```
itaybz@itaybz-ub-pc:/usr/local/bin$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
itaybz@itaybz-ub-pc:/usr/local/bin$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Is your pip3 up-to-date? You could also remove the version specification in the requirements file and just use what you have.

Comment: Try running `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools pip`